# HSQLDB - Why can't I set the default value to -1

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I'm using a HSQLDB and when I set the default value of a column to -1, I get the following Error.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: -
```

The SQL statement I use to create the table with the default value -1 looks like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE "BLAH" (
    "COL" INTEGER DEFAULT -1,
    ...
  ) ;
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Is this not possible with HSQLDB? I've exported the DDL statements from an oracle db and changed them a bit so that all datatypes are compatible with HSQLDB. Therefore the statement should work, only the default value makes troubles.

Comment: I tried even zero, something like "COL" INTEGER DEFAULT 0, but nothing works. 
Didn't find anything by googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course HSQLDB supports this.

Are you sure there is a minus size in your code? You may have used a different symbol that looks like a minus sign.

Comment: I'll try that but since I've exported the script from the Oracle SQL Developer I'm pretty sure it is a minus symbol.

Comment: Ha. That really was the problem. Thanks!